# Create pi_linkTP_keepPIvars with another ExtensonKey

Tags: typo3

is it possible to use the typo3 function pi_linkTP_keepPIvars to create a link with piVars for a another extension (communication of 2 extension).

Extension 1 say with piVars Extension 2: open singleview with single = 1.

When i use pi_linkTP_keepPIvars in extension 1, the function use the extensionkey (tx_extension1_pi1) of extension 1 but extension 2 must habe in the function the extension key of themselves (tx_extension2_pi1).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set the `$this->prefixId` to something else before the call to the link method and then set it back afterwards.

```
$temp = $this->prefixId;
$this->prefixId = 'tx_extension2_pi1';
$myLink = $this->pi_linkTP_keepPIvars(...);
$this->prefixId = $temp;
```

This is kind of dirty, but the whole pibase way of developing is anyway, so I think it's ok.